# Problem returning JSON data from table with more than one row

Tags: json, oracle, oracle19c

**Environment**: I’m using Oracle 19c database, so I am using the JSON functions declared already in PLSQL (for instance JSON_TABLE).

**What I am trying to do:** I am trying to query JSON data from a CLOB column when there are multiple rows in the CLOB table

**Problem:** When I have one row in the base table (with the CLOB column containing the JSON data), I can query the JSON data successfully but when I add a second row to the base table my query fails with an ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row.

**Example:**
I created a table with a CLOB to hold JSON data.

```
Create Table MY_RECEIVED_DATA
(LOAD_ID            NUMBER  GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
   DATE_LOADED      DATE    DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
   DATA_BUCKET      CLOB    CONSTRAINT check_json CHECK (DATA_BUCKET IS JSON))
LOB (DATA_BUCKET) STORE AS SECUREFILE (
  TABLESPACE  MYTAB
  ENABLE      STORAGE IN ROW
  CHUNK       8192
  RETENTION
  NOCACHE
  LOGGING)   
TABLESPACE MYTAB;
```

I then inserted 3 rows into the table showing the employees of Acme Inc.

```
insert into MY_RECIEVED_DATA (DATA_BUCKET)
VALUES ('[
    {   "displayName":  "McNubbins, Bubba",
        "employeeType":  "Minion",
        "givenName":  "Bubba",
        "company":  "Acme Inc"},
    {   "displayName":  "Blorgg, Gupda",
        "employeeType":  "Minion Supervisor",
        "givenName":  "Goopy",
        "company":  "Acme Inc"},
    {   "displayName":  "Zumba, Blippins",
        "employeeType":  "Overlord",
        "givenName":  "Blippy",
        "company":  "Acme Inc"}
    ]');
    Commit;
```

I then ran this select to see if I had any data and got this result

```
select * from MY_RECIEVED_DATA;

LOAD_ID DATE_LOADED          DATA_BUCKET
4       8/2/2022 1:45:16 PM  (CLOB)
```

I then ran this query to look at the JSON data in the DATA_BUCKET with these results

```
select *
from json_table((select DATA_BUCKET from MY_RECIEVED_DATA), '$[*]' 
     COLUMNS ("displayName", "employeeType","givenName","company")) jt 
group by "displayName","employeeType","givenName","company";

DISPLAYNAME       EMPLOYEETYPE       GIVENNAME    COMPANY
McNubbins, Bubba  Minion             Bubba        Acme Inc
Blorgg, Gupda     Minion Supervisor  Goopy        Acme Inc
Zumba, Blippins   Overlord           Blippy       Acme Inc
```

I then insert my second row of data

```
insert into MY_RECIEVED_DATA (DATA_BUCKET)
VALUES ('[
    {   "displayName":  "Corbin, Sammy",
        "employeeType":  "Jr. Minion",
        "givenName":  "Slimy",
        "company":  "Pipe Wrenches Llc."},
    {   "displayName":  "Zima, Dancy",
        "employeeType":  "Minion",
        "givenName":  "Dancy",
        "company":  "Pipe Wrenches Llc."},
    {   "displayName":  "Hoptom, Clarence",
        "employeeType":  "Overlord",
        "givenName":  "Sir",
        "company":  "Pipe Wrenches Llc."}
    ]');
    Commit;
```

I then re-ran this select to see if I had any data and got this result

```
select * from MY_RECIEVED_DATA;

LOAD_ID DATE_LOADED          DATA_BUCKET
4       8/2/2022 1:45:16 PM  (CLOB)
5       8/2/2022 2:10:34 PM  (CLOB)
```

So now I have two rows both containing JSON data in the DATA_BUCKET column.  I then run this same query to get the JSON columns

```
select *
from json_table((select DATA_BUCKET from MY_RECIEVED_DATA), '$[*]' 
     COLUMNS ("displayName", "employeeType","givenName","company")) jt 
group by "displayName","employeeType","givenName","company";
```

When I run the select I get the following error:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

The system will be updating the table several time a day and we will have to process each new row's JSON data.

**Question:**
How can I query multiple rows of JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a subquery; join the real table to the `json_table` clause:

```
select jt.*
from MY_RECEIVED_DATA mrd
cross apply json_table(
    mrd.DATA_BUCKET,
    '$[*]' 
    COLUMNS (
        "displayName", "employeeType","givenName","company"
    )
) jt
```

| displayName | employeeType | givenName | company |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| McNubbins, Bubba | Minion | Bubba | Acme Inc |
| Blorgg, Gupda | Minion Supervisor | Goopy | Acme Inc |
| Zumba, Blippins | Overlord | Blippy | Acme Inc |
| Corbin, Sammy | Jr. Minion | Slimy | Pipe Wrenches Llc. |
| Zima, Dancy | Minion | Dancy | Pipe Wrenches Llc. |
| Hoptom, Clarence | Overlord | Sir | Pipe Wrenches Llc. |

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=1fdf7f44a505c244f530747a29432bf4)

Not sure why you have the group-by clause; it works with or without it, but it isn't really adding anything. If you think you might have duplicates then you can use `distinct` instead of grouping.

I'd also suggest you give the columns non-quoted aliases, [as in this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d6062ca7619aa8ef7c7284524823e1b4), but it depends how you'll use the result.